# How to pass message from chrome to extension to developer?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I have a small chrome extension that helps users to quickly search for Pokémon Content and I'd like to know if there is a way to pass a message from my users to me...
I'd like to do this to get data from my users, data like what is being searched most, the most used options, things like this for curiosity...
Is there any way to do something like this?
I thought about creating another extension to pass message, but as far as I know, Chrome Extensions can only pass messages to another extension the user has...
So, is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send the information to a server and store it in a database, or a log file of some kind. I know I've used multiple chrome extensions of some kind in the past that use a connection to a server hosted by the company/developer that created the plugin.